# Адрес поддомена

Tags: php, centos, ispmanager

Есть домен site.ru. У него субдомен sub.site.ru. Файлы суб домена находятся в папке другого пользователя(не владельца site.ru) на сервере. 
Задача такая. Нужно что бы суб домен был доступен по адресу site.ru/sub, при этом находясь в директории НЕ site.ru
Сервер управляется ISPmanager.

Comment: Так вставьте iframe на страницу   site.ru/sub

Comment: Нужно что бы все файлы и каталоги сайта были доступны по аналогичному пути, фрейм этого не сделает

Comment: Тогда наверное только переносить.